# Are there closed Riemann surfaces without non-constant holomorphic functions?

Tags: complex-geometry, riemann-surfaces

I came across the [Handbook of Teichmuller Theory](https://books.google.com/books?id=oxGC6BLK0TQC&pg=PA771&lpg=PA771&dq=identifying%20riemann%20surfaces%20function%20fields&source=bl&ots=x25mIDu1zZ&sig=_wEGIkNnckFxSyZWwNk0Zb5MoaQ&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0CEwQ6AEwBWoVChMI1P-G6-3UyAIVQsFjCh02DQXM#v=onepage&q=identifying%20riemann%20surfaces%20function%20fields&f=false), and they talk about "closed Riemann surfaces with non-constant holomorphic functions".

Are there Riemann surfaces without those functions?

Comment: Your statement is quite weird if closed means compact without boundary.

Comment: The title reads "...closed Riemann surfaces **without** non-constant holomorphic functions?" The question body reads "closed Riemann surfaces **with** non-constant holomorphic functions". Could you please edit the question to clarify what exactly you're asking (and/or select Glougloubarbaki's answer if it resolves your question)? Thanks. :)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, every compact Riemann surface (hint: maximum modulus principle!)

Comment: I think your hint proves the converse, i.e. that on a compact Riemann surface every holomorphic function is constant